# Access 2007 - Inherited another user's project. Why do some of his forms NOT show up in the navigation pane?

Tags: microsoft-access-2007

I inherited an Access 2007 frontend with a SQL Server 2XXX backend and need to make some basic changes to the interface. The problem is, some of the forms I need to edit are nowhere to be found in the navigation pane, though some of them are in fact accessible through the switchboard. Unfortunately I cannot access all the forms I need through the switchboard alone.

Any idea why some forms would not be shown on the navigation pane?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it turns out they were just straight-up hidden. Why some forms were hidden and some weren't is beyond me. Security through half-cocked obscurity, I guess.

Anyway, to fix it I right clicked on the Navigation Pane and went to Navigation Options. Under there I checked Show Hidden Objects and Show System Objects and all the hidden forms were revealed.